# rotating columns into rows with excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

[image]

dont ask me how this happened, but somehow things that should be columns are in this sheet as rows...

you can see the repeating Account numbers and the words in column c, imagine everything rotated 180 degrees. And insert blanks or nulls for the field that doesnt exist for that specific Account number.

In short it should end up looking like this:

[image]

I cant think of an easy way to do this inside of excel. But perhaps with some VBA code?

what would be the easiest solution? and how do I implement it?

I know this question isnt very clear, but if you leave some directing comments, I would be happy to edit this question till it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to automate this? or is it a one-time problem? Copy-> Paste (Transpose) ?

Comment: not sure yet. i will update when I know

Comment: Unfortunately Copy paste transpose is not the solution in this case as the Field Description is not in a fixed sequence

Comment: Just found, this will need to be automated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this :)

I am taking a selective example to show how you can proceed.

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

Now, create a Pivot of your data. This will give you unique Account numbers. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Then create a table with the respective headers as shown in your screenshot and copy and paste the unique Account Number from your pivot there.

[image]

Now you are ready to pull up your data. So as per the above screenshots enter this formula in cell `B13`. Note this is an Array formula. You have to press <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$5,MATCH(1,($C$2:$C$5=B12)*($A$2:$A$5=A13),0))
```

[image]

Simply do that for the rest :)